# How to fix this error on DAC0808 with LF351?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source, voltage-measurement, dac, output

[image]

I am testing this schematic from the [DAC0808 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac0808.pdf) at 10kHz frequency digital input, current 0, 1 and 2 mA but output had error see fig.Vout should slightly than this. How can I decrease this problem?

[image]

I had capture signal at inverting input of LF351 it is not slightly GND(0V).

[image]

Comment: Phongpit Sribua - Hi, You have posted a few questions about the DAC0808 recently. This one seems related to [an earlier question of yours](/q/668376) when using the same IC. If this question today obsoletes that earlier question, then please delete that one. However if both questions are still needed then please edit *both* of them, to explain how the questions are different, explain any overlap (i.e. will an answer to one question also answer the other one?), and explain exactly *why* they are *both* needed. From a quick review, they both seem to be asking about some kind of output offset...

Comment: Phongpit Sribua - Hi, Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that copied content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked (references for books / articles should include title, author(s), publisher, edition, page numbers etc.). In order to help you, I found what I believe to be the source PDF link in this case and added it for you. For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) Thanks.

Comment: SamGibson - Hi I am sorry about 2 post quickly I use DAC0808 for my research and first post I do not understand about timing change logic high to low but now I am clearly about it. I will delete it.Second post different at this point when I use 10kHz frequency it had problem about Damp signal which at 1kHz it is not have this damp signal .

Comment: SamGibson - Thank you about notice me of reference circuit I am sorry. I will not do like this and add it to correctly.

Comment: Phongpit Sribua - Thanks for your reply. One final point from me: You said: "*when I use 10kHz frequency it had problem about Damp signal which at 1kHz it is not have this damp signal*". (a) I don't know what you mean by "Damp signal". Other people might know that terminology, but to help people to help you, please [edit] the question & explain what you mean. (b) This seems to be the first time you have mentioned a difference between the behaviours at 10 kHz & 1 kHz. Again, please [edit] the question to ensure all relevant details, test & troubleshooting results etc. are included there. Thanks